# Can I distort a pattern that I have created in Photoshop in a circular way?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, distort

Can I apply any pattern that I have created in Photoshop in a circular way as if the pattern itself was emerging out of the centre of the circle? I tried to scale, distort, add filters and everything but I am just not able to figure out how to do that.

This image is the reference image for what I am trying to achieve:

[image: example image]

Comment: Polar coordinate transform?

Comment: I tried that too. But it does not give the exact result

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't think Photoshop would be the best software to create something like that. Have you access to Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape perhaps? It's pretty easy to create repeating circular patterns in vector image editing software.

Comment: The problem is i am more familiar to Photoshop therefore i was thinking if there was a way to do it here.

Comment: Thats weird doing polar coordinates works for me. Perhaps you dont know how polar coordinates is supposed to be used? But i agree i wouldnt do this in photoshop since youd need so much over resolution for not much gain. When all you have is a hammer, everything ends up looking like a nail.

Comment: There are tutorials on the internet for creating similar patterns which you could use if you aren't familiar with the software - like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX-h7Kr6dj0

Comment: Could you please help me in how to use the polar coordinates effectively?

Comment: Actually the polar coordinates works pretty well. Thanks for all your replies. it was really helpful.